# Replace items of a longer list with matches from a shorter list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My goal is to compare two lists as follows:

Take every item in `long_list` and compare it for substrings to the entire `short_list`. If there is a match, add the item from the `short_list` to `new_list`. If no match, then insert 'NA' to `new_list`.

The issue with my current solution is, that the items from the `long_list` are inserted into `new_list` instead of the items from the `short_list`. How can I access `b`.

```
long_list = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'KLM']
short_list = ['aABCa', 'xYZz']

new_list = [x if any(x.lower() in b.lower() for b in short_list) else 'NA' for x in long_list].
```

**Current output:**

new_list = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'NA', 'NA', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'NA']

**Goal:**

new_list = ['aABCa', 'aABCa', 'NA', 'NA', 'xXYZz', 'aABCa', 'xXYZz', 'NA']

Comment: Why do you have the long strings in `short_list` and the short strings in `long_list`?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple matches?

Comment: The items in ```short_list``` are unique. There will be multiple matches and all of them should be replaced by the item from the ```short_list```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutly want to do it with a comprehension list you can use the folowing

```py
>>> new_list = [next((y for y in short_list if x.lower() in y.lower()),'NA') for x in long_list]
>>> new_list
['aABCa', 'aABCa', 'NA', 'NA', 'xYZz', 'aABCa', 'xYZz', 'NA']
```

But a for loop might be clearer in this case

Comment: It doesn't have to be a list comprehension... But your code works perfectly, thank you!